# Create XML based on puppet templates with correct custom values?

Tags: ruby, xml, templates, puppet

In a database config setup I have 20 something XML files with the database connection information.

They have all exactly the same content except the connection information that is different. I have to use these XML files for five different environments, so instead of updating them manually I was hoping there was a good way to update their content with puppet, as I use this to set up the rest of the environment:

```
<config-property-setting name="DatabaseName"></config-property-setting>
<config-property-setting name="Password"></config-property-setting>
<config-property-setting name="UserName"></config-property-setting>
<config-property-setting name="ServerName"></config-property-setting>
<config-property-setting name="DriverType"></config-property-setting>
<config-property-setting name="MaxStatements"></config-property-setting>
<config-property-setting name="NetworkProtocol"></config-property-setting>
<config-property-setting name="PortNumber"></config-property-setting>
<config-property-setting name="LoginTimeout"></config-property-setting>
```

These are the values needed to be changed for each XML file.

Is there a good way to have a config file where the values for these files are entered and then, through templates, are pushed out as the correct configured and named XML files?

Comment: What have you tried? It's not hard to do what you want, but it takes a bit of knowledge of XML generation. Nokogiri can be used for that, as can ERB. Puppet would be how the files get pushed out, but generating them should be done using Ruby or another language.

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way to do that in pure puppet is probably by using Hiera and an Erb template.

First of all, make sure that your `hiera.yaml` contains a hierarchy appropriate for your use case. For example, if the distinct environments are in distinct domains (but it might be more common to use the `environment` variable) :

```
:hierarchy:
  - "%{module_name}/%{::fqdn}"
  - "%{module_name}/%{::domain}"
  - "%{module_name}/global"
  - "global"
```

Then you can store the various configuration values just as @mudasobwa suggested, for example in `hieradata/xmlmodule/domain1.internal` :

```
:properties:
  :DatabaseName : 'name'
  :Password : 'pwd'
  :UserName : 'user'
  :ServerName : 'server'
  :DriverType : 'mysql'
  :MaxStatements : 30
  :NetworkProtocol : 'udp'
  :PortNumber : 1234
  :LoginTimeout : 60
```

Then it's as simple as :

```
$properties = hiera('properties')
file { '/where/the/xml/fileS/goes.xml':
    content => template('template.xml.erb');
}
```

And you get the values you need in the `properties` hash :

```
<config-property-setting name="DatabaseName">
    <%=properties['DatabaseName']%>
</config-property-setting>
<config-property-setting name="Password">
    <%=properties['Password']%>
</config-property-setting>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use pure ruby for that. First of all, create [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) config file:

```
:properties:
  :DatabaseName : 'name'
  :Password : 'pwd'
  :UserName : 'user'
  :ServerName : 'server'
  :DriverType : 'mysql'
  :MaxStatements : 30
  :NetworkProtocol : 'udp'
  :PortNumber : 1234
  :LoginTimeout : 60
```

Then use this ruby code to produce what you need:

```
require 'yaml'
cfg = YAML.load_file 'cfg.yml'
xml = cfg[:properties].map { |k, v|
  "<config-property-setting name='#{k}'>#{v}</config-property-setting>"  
}.join("\n")
```

And, finally, inject these values into xml config *templates* (there must be a placeholder within xml configs to denote the place for proper values, e. g. if you want to insert them right after the root node `<root>`):

```
xml_config_files.each { |file|
  File.write(file, File.read(f).gsub /<root>/m, "<root>\n#{xml}\n")
}
```

Hope it helps.